# Concurent DELETE with condition

Tags: postgresql, locking

For example, I have `articles`, and `authors`. An `article` needs at least one author. But you can delete multiple `authors` at the same time and concurrently. So I need to prevent having a state where the `articles` doesn't have any `authors`.

I thought about using advisory lock and does this:

```
--- Setup

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS advisory;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS advisory.authors;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS advisory.articles;

CREATE TABLE advisory.articles (
    articleid bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    text text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE advisory.authors (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    articleid bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES advisory.articles (articleid),
    name text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO advisory.articles (text)
        VALUES ('article 1'),('article 2');
INSERT INTO advisory.authors (articleid, name)
        VALUES (1,'a'),(1,'b'),(1,'c'),(2,'alone');

--- Final query

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
   SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(2); --article id

   WITH authors_count_per_article AS 
   (
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM advisory.authors
     WHERE articleid = 2
   )
   DELETE 
   FROM advisory.authors
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM authors_count_per_article WHERE count > 1)
      AND advisory.authors.name = 'alone'; -- will return 0 because only one author
COMMIT;
```

1. Is it a good thing to use an advisory lock like this?
2. Is there a better way to write the query where I check for the author count? I find it quite complicated.
3. Any tips for a good lock id?

I am using PostgreSQL 10

Comment: Your version of Postgres? And `An article needs always one author` is supposed to mean *at least* one author, I assume?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter PostgreSQL 10. and yes. I will change the text.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I would love to get your answer if you have time. Thank you so much.